# UIView Becomes Visible Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

When we change the hidden property of a view than is there a way to identify the exact point where view becomes completely visible or hidden i.e drawing operation gets completed.

In my app I have to take the screenshot once the view gets hide, currently I have added a delay of 330ms just to make sure that the view is completely hidden, I want to get rid of this arbitrary delay.

I have already tried couple of things like KVO on view hidden property, I subclass UIView class and try to utilize viewDidMoveToSuperView delegate also, but all these things does not guaranteed that the view drawing has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas come immediately to mind:

1. schedule a block on the main queue which will presumably be called after the next iteration of the run loop (by which time view redrawing should have occurred).

   ```
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // take your snapshot
   });
   ```
2. manipulate the view's opacity in an animation block (`hidden` cannot be animated but `alpha` can) and employ the completion handler.

   ```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
       view.alpha = 0;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       // take your snapshot
   }];
   ```

Comment: When animation duration is set to 0 than completion block gets called immediately. I tried these ways and they didn't help, so I was wondering if there is some sort of delegate/notification/callback which guaranteed they view drawing gets completed.

Comment: @MohammadSalman: what approach are you using to make the screenshot?

Comment: I have tried mutliple ways to take screenshot like below `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size‌​, self.view.opaque, 0.0);`
`[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`
`UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`
`UIGraphicsEndImageContext();'
But still the issue I am facing (I have seen other posts also similar to my problem) that I can't find a way to make sure that view drawing has got finish, without adding any arbitrary delay in code.